# AttributeError when running pip in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I recently upgraded python from 2.7.6 to 2.7.9 using homebrew. I then tried to 'revirtualise' an **existing virtual environment**:

```
sudo virtualenv -p python2.7 existingvenv
```

But am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv.../bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "venv.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "venv.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/log.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip import backwardcompat
  File "venv.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/backwardcompat/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from urllib2 import URLError, HTTPError
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 93, in <module>
    import hashlib
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 138, in <module>
    _hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2352, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 825, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 993, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 961, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 903, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/robertelliott...hflow-app/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

I also get the above error when running any `pip install x` inside the above active virtual environment.

I don't get the error when creating a **new virtualenv**:

```
$ virtualenv -p python2.7 newvenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
New python executable in newenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

Is there an old symlink or something inside the existing virtualenv causing the issue and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Why don't you just use a new virtualenv? Install packages from the existing requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a new feature in Python, which wheel 0.24 is not compatible with. You'll find a folder called `virtualenv_support` containing base install files for setuptools, pip, and wheel under your Python 2.7 system install. There are a few solutions. The easiest is to just remove wheel-0.24* from the `virtualenv_support` folder. If you want to go a step farther, you could download version 0.26 of the wheel .whl file and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

`sudo virtualenv --clear -p python2.7 existingvenv`

?